# Determine which microphone source to use for Azure Cognitive Services with Python

Tags: python, objective-c, azure, azure-cognitive-services

I've set up an instance of Azure Cognitive Services to listen on a microphone for a key phrase. This works fine, however I'm unable to tell it to listen to a specific microphone on my Apple Mac.

The code I have is:

```py
mic_name = self.preferences.get('mic_name', None)
self.audio_config = speechsdk.audio.AudioConfig(device_name=mic_name) if mic_name else None
...
self.keyword_recognizer = speechsdk.KeywordRecognizer(audio_config=self.audio_config)
```

Where I'm providing the microphone name as the device name to the `speechsdk.audio.AudioConfig` library. However from what I can read via https://aka.ms/csspeech/microphone-selection it seems I need to provide the device ID, not the name or index which is what pyaudio gives me.

I've been searching online in an attempt to find a solution to getting the device ID, and the only thing I've been able to determine is that the pyobjc package might be needed in order to interact with the hardware via objective-c. Yet my attempts at that have also failed.

Does anyone know of an existing library, or example I could reference, where a Python script is able to return the ID of a microphone device so I can provide it to the Speech Services SDK? (I also want this to work for windows, but that is a seperate matter)

===

Update - to be clear, I need the user to be able to select the microphone they want to use from a dropdown, and then pass said Microphone ID through to the `speechsdk.audio.AudioConfig` library.

Answer (score 0):

***Updated Solution2 with Device Id:-***

After multiple trial and error, I have used subprocess module to directly run powershell command in Python and retrieve Device_Id of Microphone then use the same device Id in the **`audio_config  =  speechsdk.audio.AudioConfig(device_name=mic_device_id)`**

My code:-

```py
import subprocess
import azure.cognitiveservices.speech as speechsdk

def get_audio_devices():
    try:
        # Execute PowerShell command to get audio devices
        command = ['powershell', 'Get-WmiObject Win32_SoundDevice | Select-Object DeviceID, Name']
        process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        output, error = process.communicate()

        # Print out any error message
        if error:
            print(f"Error: {error.decode()}")

        # Decode and split the output to extract device ID and name
        output_lines = output.decode().strip().split('\n')[2:]  # Skip first two lines (column headers)
        if output_lines:
            devices = []
            for line in output_lines:
                device_id, name = line.strip().split(None, 1)  # Split on first whitespace
                devices.append((device_id.strip(), name.strip()))
            return devices
        else:
            print("No audio devices found.")
            return []
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error: {e}")
        return []

def text_to_speech(text, mic_device_id):
    speech_config = speechsdk.SpeechConfig(subscription="de63f99217074bd88429dbc7ccb45a10", region="eastus")
    audio_config = speechsdk.audio.AudioConfig(device_name=mic_device_id)
    speech_synthesizer = speechsdk.SpeechSynthesizer(speech_config=speech_config, audio_config=audio_config)

    # Synthesize text to speech
    result = speech_synthesizer.speak_text_async(text).get()
    if result.reason == speechsdk.ResultReason.SynthesizingAudioCompleted:
        print("Speech synthesized successfully")
    elif result.reason == speechsdk.ResultReason.Canceled:
        cancellation_details = result.cancellation_details
        print("Speech synthesis canceled:", cancellation_details.reason)
        if cancellation_details.reason == speechsdk.CancellationReason.Error:
            print("Error details:", cancellation_details.error_details)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Get the list of audio devices
    devices = get_audio_devices()
    
    # Print the list of devices
    for index, device in enumerate(devices, start=1):
        print(f"{index}. DeviceID: {device[0]}, Name: {device[1]}")
    
    # Prompt the user to enter the microphone device ID directly
    mic_device_id = input("Enter the DeviceID of the microphone you want to use: ")
    text = input("Enter the text you want to synthesize and speak: ")
    text_to_speech(text, mic_device_id)
import subprocess
import azure.cognitiveservices.speech as speechsdk

def get_audio_devices():
    try:
        # Execute PowerShell command to get audio devices
        command = ['powershell', 'Get-WmiObject Win32_SoundDevice | Select-Object DeviceID, Name']
        process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        output, error = process.communicate()

        # Print out any error message
        if error:
            print(f"Error: {error.decode()}")

        # Decode and split the output to extract device ID and name
        output_lines = output.decode().strip().split('\n')[2:]  # Skip first two lines (column headers)
        if output_lines:
            devices = []
            for line in output_lines:
                device_id, name = line.strip().split(None, 1)  # Split on first whitespace
                devices.append((device_id.strip(), name.strip()))
            return devices
        else:
            print("No audio devices found.")
            return []
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error: {e}")
        return []

def text_to_speech(text, mic_device_id):
    speech_config = speechsdk.SpeechConfig(subscription="de63f99217074bd88429dbc7ccb45a10", region="eastus")
    audio_config = speechsdk.audio.AudioConfig(device_name=mic_device_id)
    speech_synthesizer = speechsdk.SpeechSynthesizer(speech_config=speech_config, audio_config=audio_config)

    # Synthesize text to speech
    result = speech_synthesizer.speak_text_async(text).get()
    if result.reason == speechsdk.ResultReason.SynthesizingAudioCompleted:
        print("Speech synthesized successfully")
    elif result.reason == speechsdk.ResultReason.Canceled:
        cancellation_details = result.cancellation_details
        print("Speech synthesis canceled:", cancellation_details.reason)
        if cancellation_details.reason == speechsdk.CancellationReason.Error:
            print("Error details:", cancellation_details.error_details)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Get the list of audio devices
    devices = get_audio_devices()
    
    # Print the list of devices
    for index, device in enumerate(devices, start=1):
        print(f"{index}. DeviceID: {device[0]}, Name: {device[1]}")
    
    # Prompt the user to enter the microphone device ID directly
    mic_device_id = input("Enter the DeviceID of the microphone you want to use: ")
    text = input("Enter the text you want to synthesize and speak: ")
    text_to_speech(text, mic_device_id)
```

**Output:-**

[image]

***Just retreive Mic ID:-***

**For Windows:-**

```py
import subprocess

def get_audio_devices():
    try:
        # Execute PowerShell command to get audio devices
        command = ['powershell', 'Get-WmiObject Win32_SoundDevice | Select-Object DeviceID, Name']
        process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        output, error = process.communicate()

        # Print the raw output from PowerShell
        print("Raw Output from PowerShell:")
        print(output.decode())

        # Print out any error message
        if error:
            print(f"Error: {error.decode()}")

        # Decode and split the output to extract device ID and name
        output_lines = output.decode().strip().split('\n')[2:]  # Skip first two lines (column headers)
        if output_lines:
            for line in output_lines:
                device_id, name = line.strip().split(None, 1)  # Split on first whitespace
                print(f"DeviceID: {device_id.strip()}, Name: {name.strip()}")
        else:
            print("No audio devices found.")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error: {e}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    get_audio_devices()
```

**Output:-**

[image]

**For MAC:-**

```py
import subprocess

def get_audio_devices():
    try:
        # Execute system_profiler command to get audio devices
        command = ['system_profiler', 'SPAudioDataType']
        process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        output, error = process.communicate()

        # Print the raw output from system_profiler
        print("Raw Output from system_profiler:")
        print(output.decode())

        # Print out any error message
        if error:
            print(f"Error: {error.decode()}")

        # Decode and split the output to extract device ID and name
        devices = []
        output_lines = output.decode().strip().split('\n\n')
        for device_info in output_lines:
            if 'Devices' in device_info:
                lines = device_info.split('\n')
                for line in lines:
                    if 'Device Name:' in line:
                        device_name = line.split(': ')[1]
                    elif 'Device ID:' in line:
                        device_id = line.split(': ')[1]
                        devices.append((device_id.strip(), device_name.strip()))
                        break  # Move to the next device
        if devices:
            return devices
        else:
            print("No audio devices found.")
            return []
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error: {e}")
        return []

if __name__ == "__main__":
    get_audio_devices()
```

**Updated Solution:-**

Try the code below where I have retrieved the list of Microphone in the output, And allowed user to Pass the Microphone Index, then passed the Mic_Id in the audio.config:-

```py
import azure.cognitiveservices.speech as speechsdk
import sounddevice as sd
import soundfile as sf

def get_microphone_devices():
    devices = sd.query_devices()
    return devices

def select_microphone():
    print("Available microphones:")
    devices = get_microphone_devices()
    for i, device in enumerate(devices):
        print(f"{i}: {device['name']}")
    
    device_index = int(input("Select microphone index: "))
    return devices[device_index]['name']

def text_to_speech(text, output_file, mic_device_id):
    # Set up the speech config
    speech_config = speechsdk.SpeechConfig(subscription="de63f99217074bd88429dbc7ccb45a10", region="eastus")

    # Create an audio configuration specifying the selected microphone device
    audio_config = speechsdk.audio.AudioConfig(device_name=mic_device_id)

    # Create a speech synthesizer object
    speech_synthesizer = speechsdk.SpeechSynthesizer(speech_config=speech_config, audio_config=audio_config)

    # Synthesize the text to speech
    result = speech_synthesizer.speak_text_async(text).get()

    # Save the speech output to a file
    if result.reason == speechsdk.ResultReason.SynthesizingAudioCompleted:
        audio_data = result.audio_data
        sf.write(output_file, audio_data, 16000)

def main():
    mic_device_id = select_microphone()
    text = input("Enter the text to convert to speech: ")
    output_file = "output.wav"
    text_to_speech(text, output_file, mic_device_id)
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

[image]

***Approach 1:-***

Use the code below to select the available Microphone or Audio devices and then get the speech output:-

```py
import azure.cognitiveservices.speech as speechsdk
import sounddevice as sd
import soundfile as sf

def text_to_speech(text, output_file):
    # Set up the speech config
    speech_config = speechsdk.SpeechConfig(subscription="xxxxxxx5a10", region="eastus")

    # Create a speech synthesizer object
    speech_synthesizer = speechsdk.SpeechSynthesizer(speech_config=speech_config)

    # Synthesize the text to speech
    result = speech_synthesizer.speak_text_async(text).get()

    # Save the speech output to a file
    if result.reason == speechsdk.ResultReason.SynthesizingAudioCompleted:
        audio_data = result.audio_data
        sf.write(output_file, audio_data, 16000)

def select_microphone():
    print("Available microphones:")
    for i, device in enumerate(sd.query_devices()):
        print(f"{i}: {device['name']}")
    
    device_index = int(input("Select microphone index: "))
    return device_index

def main():
    device_index = select_microphone()
    text = input("Enter the text to convert to speech: ")
    output_file = "output.wav"
    text_to_speech(text, output_file)
    
    play_audio_file(output_file, device_index)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**Output:-**

[image]

***Approach 2:-***

Alternatively, You can directly add the Microphone Device ID in your code and get the speech output in that specific Mic:-
In order to get **`Microphone Device ID`** in your **MAC device** use the command in your terminal:-

```
system_profiler SPAudioDataType
```

This will list the audio devices along with their **`ID's`**, Now use the **`Microphone Id`** in the code below:-

```py
import os
import azure.cognitiveservices.speech as speechsdk


mic_device_id = "INTELAUDIO\FUNC_xxxxxxxx_xxxxxEV_10xx\5&1xxxx001"


speech_config = speechsdk.SpeechConfig(subscription='de63f99217074bd88429dbc7ccb45a10', region="eastus")


audio_config = speechsdk.audio.AudioConfig(device_name=mic_device_id)


speech_config.speech_synthesis_voice_name='en-US-JennyNeural'

speech_synthesizer = speechsdk.SpeechSynthesizer(speech_config=speech_config, audio_config=audio_config)


print("Enter some text that you want to speak >")
text = input()

speech_synthesis_result = speech_synthesizer.speak_text_async(text).get()

if speech_synthesis_result.reason == speechsdk.ResultReason.SynthesizingAudioCompleted:
    print("Speech synthesized for text [{}]".format(text))
elif speech_synthesis_result.reason == speechsdk.ResultReason.Canceled:
    cancellation_details = speech_synthesis_result.cancellation_details
    print("Speech synthesis canceled: {}".format(cancellation_details.reason))
    if cancellation_details.reason == speechsdk.CancellationReason.Error:
        if cancellation_details.error_details:
            print("Error details: {}".format(cancellation_details.error_details))
            print("set the resource key and region values?")
```

***Output:-***

[image]

Comment: Okay I don't think this exactly answers my question...

So the issue I have is that I want the user to be able to select their microphone source - which means that I need to show a list of the microphones and then let retrieve the ID. This microphone is then what I need for the speechsdk.KeywordRecognizer 

I cant manually specify the ID as I won't know it - and I need the ID to pass through to speechsdk.audio.AudioConfig

Comment: @Dan The Approach 1 code shows the list of Microphone and you can use one of the microphone in your speech recognizer.

Comment: the issue is that the speechsdk.audio.AudioConfig package requires a device ID, not an index

Comment: @Dan check the **Updated Solution** in my updated answer now with the new code that uses audioConfig and the Mic selected from the Listed option

Comment: Your updated solution uses the mic name, not the ID - I've tried passing it the name (see my initial question), but it doesn't pick up the microphone based on the name. As such, I want to find the device ID to pass through. I appreciate your help, but I think you're maybe not understanding the issue?

Comment: @Dan  Check my ***Updated Solution2 with Device Id:-***  in my updated answer, it meets your current requirement